# DateTime Uncaught exception DateTime::__construct()

Tags: php, html, date

Yesterday i was working on a website that we are gona use.
It worked good etc. However when i start it right now, i get a error...

We get information from a other website wich posts the date like this:

> 2016-30-24T11:30:00.000+01:00

However we only want to show:

> 11:30:00

Hours Minuts and Seconds.

We did it with the folowing method:

```
$start_time = new DateTime($meeting->start, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo '<p><b>Start:</b> ' . date_format($start_time, 'H:i:s') . '</p>';
```

This was working yesterday, however now i get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
>   'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string
>   (2016-21-24T08:21:00.000+01:00) at position 6 (1): Unexpected
>   character' in index.php:58 Stack trace: #0
>   index.php(58): DateTime->__construct('2016-21-24T08:2...',
>   Object(DateTimeZone)) #1 {main} thrown in
>   index.php on line 58

How do i solve this error, and why was it working yesterday and not now?

Answer (score 2):

The exception is telling you that the date is nonsense, to which I'd agree.
Neither the 24th of the 21st month nor the 21st of the 24th month makes any sense.

Comment: oops great catch, i deleted my answer